# How to adjust battery threshold on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: power-management, asus, battery, tlp

I tried tlp and set

`START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=0 
 STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=60`

and it didn't work
I have a Asus vivobook s14

Comment: Stating to charge at 0 would mean dead battery and laptop shuts off at 2 percent right?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [command line application](https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat) that does this.

The easiest way to get started is download the app from the [releases page](https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat/releases/) and run

```
$ ./bat --help
```

from the terminal in the directory where it is located which should show the help documentation.

If there's an error, it might have to do with permissions. The following command might solve the problem.

```
chmod +x ./bat
```

Basically, running

```
$ ./bat --threshold
```

will print out the current threshold.

To set a new threshold, say 60%, run

```
./bat --threshold 60
```

To persist the current threshold between restarts, run

```
sudo ./bat --persist
```

Note: Persisting uses [systemd](https://systemd.io/) under the hood but this is bundled with most Linux distributions including Ubuntu.

Tip: Putting the app in a directory like `/usr/local/bin/` that is in the `$PATH` will enable you to run it from anywhere and not just in the directory the app is in. Then the above commands become,

```
bat --help
```

```
bat --threshold 60
```

```
bat --persist
```

respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Charge thresholds work for ThinkPads only – as stated in TLP's documentation and the config file itself.